# My date is not saving correctly to MySQL in the datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am having a problem with saving dates to MySQL. When I add the datetime fields they save correctly like so

> 2014-04-08 09:24:00

But when I update the data with the script below it over rights the datetime field with

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Then if I update it a second time with the correct date it saves it correctly. Then if I update something else on the page it saves it as

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

again. Any help would be appreciated. Or maybe I should just go back to saving it as a string rather than the datetime

`$signstart` and `$signend` are the date fields I am saving

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO signings(signstart,signend,custid,contact,samount,prtamount,faxamount,ordern,fname,lname,street1,street2,city,state,zip,hphone,cphone,wphone,fax,email,coname,coworkphone,pid,invoicenumber,loannumber)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['signstart'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['signend'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
            $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['custid'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['contact'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST['samount'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
            $stmt->bindParam(6, $_POST['prtamount'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
            $stmt->bindParam(7, $_POST['faxamount'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
            $stmt->bindParam(8, $_POST['ordern'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(9, $_POST['fname'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(10, $_POST['lname'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(11, $_POST['street1'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(12, $_POST['street2'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(13, $_POST['city'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(14, $_POST['state'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(15, $_POST['zip'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(16, $_POST['hphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(17, $_POST['cphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(18, $_POST['wphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(19, $_POST['fax'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(20, $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(21, $_POST['coname'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(22, $_POST['coworkphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->bindParam(23, $_POST['pid'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
            $stmt->bindParam(24, $invoicenumber, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
            $stmt->bindParam(25, $_POST['loannumber'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
            $stmt->execute(); 

 $sql = "UPDATE signings SET 
       pid = ?,
       signstart = ?, 
       signend = ?,
       custid = ?,  
       contact = ?,
       faxamount = ?,  
       samount = ?,
       prtamount = ?, 
       faxamount = ?,
       ordern = ?,
       loannumber = ?,
       fname = ?,
       lname = ?,
       street1 = ?,
       street2 = ?,
       city = ?,
       state = ?,
       zip = ?,
       hphone = ?,
       cphone = ?,
       wphone = ?,
       fax = ?,
       email = ?,
       coname = ?,
       cocellphone = ?,
       coworkphone = ?
       WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue('1', $_POST['pid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue('2', $_POST['signstart'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('3', $_POST['signend'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('4', $_POST['custid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('5', $_POST['contact'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('6', $_POST['faxamount'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue('7', $_POST['samount'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue('8', $_POST['prtamount'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue('9', $_POST['faxamount'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue('10', $_POST['ordern'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('11', $_POST['loannumber'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('12', $_POST['fname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('13', $_POST['lname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('14', $_POST['street1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('15', $_POST['street2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('16', $_POST['city'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('17', $_POST['state'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('18', $_POST['zip'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('19', $_POST['hphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('20', $_POST['cphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('21', $_POST['wphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('22', $_POST['fax'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('23', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('24', $_POST['coname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('25', $_POST['coworkphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('26', $_POST['cocellphone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('27', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the INSERT statement in your code works, but the UPDATE statement doesn't work right?

One suggestion is to not update any fields you don't need to, but if you do need to update those, what is the format coming in via $_POST['signstart'] in the POST statement? Can you print that out and make sure it's a valid format for insertion?

Comment: NO I am not saying that the INSERT statement in your code works, but the UPDATE statement doesn't work right. update works on all fields Just when I update the datetime field it changes it to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and when I update it the second time it saves it correctly. I have decided to just change it to a string  because I don't have a problem with it saving and updating in that format. I need to be able to update every field.